# Is there app for Android car dashboard, GPS, Spotify controls?

Tags: android, gps, dashboard, car, spotify

The need is to show essential info in car multimedia player, based on Android 8. I found GPS speedometer apps, but didn't find a way how to show music controls at the same time.

The player is 10", so there's plenty of room to show the info, but all apps seem to be working a full-screen mode only.

- GPS Speed
- Way to skip Spotify tracks
- Access Equalizer settings

Do I have to program my own app?

Comment: I don't have a car, so I didn't check deeply – but maybe one of the [car specific homescreens](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_launcher#group_520) fits? You didn't specify if all the details should be shown simultaneously, if trackers are acceptable, or if there's a price limit. Some of them offer voice control, so that might substitute for one or the other. [Dashlinq](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gromaudio.dashlinq) might come close (explicitly mentions Spotify).